# How to include Work-In-Progress Cucumber Tests, but not execute them

Tags: java, cucumber

Some of my cucumber scenarios are failing, and I want to mark them as *@wip* so that I can still tag them in the Runner.java class, but not actually run them.

I am tagging the failing scenarios in my .feature file like so:

```
@wip
Scenario Outline: BR001 - NEGATIVE - Description
```

And I specify the tag in the Runner class like so:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"progress",
            "html:build/report/cucumber/html",
            "junit:build/report/cucumber/junit/cucumber.xml",
            "json:build/report/cucumber/json/cucumber.json"
    },
    glue = {"qa"},
    features = {"src/test/java/features"}, 
    tags = {"@BR000,@BR004b, @BR007, @BR008, @BR009, not@wip"}
    )
public class QARunner {
```

If I remove *not@wip*, then the the other 5 tests pass fine.

What changes do I need to make so that I can include the work-in-progress tests, but not run them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out, updating the following line in the Runner.java class above like so:

```
tags = {"@BR000,@BR004b, @BR007, @BR008, @BR009", "~@wip"}
```

This executes all tests within the first quotation marks (" "), & does not execute the tags within the second pair of quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I usually write these tags separately like :
(tags = "not @wip and not @quarentena")

Comment: This is a commentary rather than an answer.